# Remove all files with different extensions and keep only one using bash regexp

Tags: regex, bash

When I'm writing a Latex file, sometimes I need to **remove all files** which were generated by its compilation and **keep only the `.tex` file**. Example, I want to remove all the following files:

```
paper-stack.log
paper-stack.blg
paper-stack.bbl
paper-stack.aux
paper-stack.pdf
```

and keep the following file:

```
paper-stack.tex
```

Besides that, I want to remove using **`bash regexp`**. I rememeber I did it before, but now I'm confused about the regexp patterns after using other shells. It was something like `rm paper-stack.[!tex]`, but I'm not sure about the metacharacters `[`, `]` and `!`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be far easier to add the rules to a `Makefile'`s `clean` target, so you could easily remove them all with one command reliably thousands of times over?

Comment: Yes, it would be. I think I should start creating `Makefile`'s to compile Latex files. Anyway, I am very interested in this command because it seems very simple and very useful for other commands. It is more a curiosity about the power of bash.

Comment: @sarnold IMHO creating a Makefile does not seem very pratical to me such as editing and compiling Latex in **Emacs** and removing the files stated above with this single command. Maybe for bigger projects, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have done `shopt extglob` then you can say something like

```
rm paper-stack.!(tex)
```

(As usual when working with `rm` or other potentially destructive commands, it's a good idea to test with `echo` first.)  I would be more explicit about what to remove though, just on general principles.

Comment: Note that this might destroy your `.bib` file, which cannot be recreated from the `.tex` file. Yes, you added a caveat about it, but this is supremely dangerous. :)

Comment: You are right! Thank you @sarnold and @geekosaur. When you are editing your Latex files, do you usually create a `Makefile` with `clean` and other targets?

Comment: Yes; not just for that reason but because sometimes you need multiple runs before everything settles down, when it needs to update backreferences and such.

Comment: To keep the .tex and .bib files: `rm -i paper-stack.!(tex|bib)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use the command find to the directory you want and remove them. Something like the following. But consider what sarnold suggested, put the command somewhere like in the makefile.

```
find my/dir/ -name "*.log" -or -name ".aux" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the nice points of creating a `Makefile` is that it can assist in running LaTeX multiple times if necessary; this is taken from a production `Makefile` that keeps a technical document up-to-date:

```make
techdoc.pdf: techdoc.tex
        while pdflatex $< ${BUILD_OUTPUT} || exit 1 ; \
                grep -q "Label(s) may have changed" techdoc.log; \
        do :; done
```

This way, just running `make` (if this is the first target in the `Makefile`) will rebuild the `techdoc.pdf` as many times as necessary to ensure that references and labels are correctly updated. (This is usually just twice, might sometimes be three times, and I've heard that someone *clever* could make input that causes a loop like this to never terminate -- but I've never seen one yet.)

Once you've got something like this in place, it's a piece of cake to keep going:

```
.PHONY: clean

clean: techdoc.log techdoc.bbl techdoc.aux techdoc.blg
        rm $?
```

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables to explain the `$?`, `$@`, and similar short-hand variables available in GNU Make.

Comment: Awesome! Very useful. I will start using `Makefile`'s. I used to find it very annoying because I had to create a new `Makefile` from the beginning, with all the rules, one by one. I believe it's a lack of practice. After learning, it will bring more long-term benefits.

Comment: Don't forget that you must indent all the lines with _tabs_ and _only_ tabs. That must be the single-most annoying aspect of `make`, every beginner hates that at least once. :)